# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type image/png

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Today, all of a sudden I started obtaining the following response in my development website:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i8!2i68!3i120!1m4!1m3!1i8!2i68!…12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e3&callback=_xdc_._pk356f&token=37643' because its MIME type ('image/png') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

This causes the tiles to not be loaded properly and its bugging the website. I've read and searched and found nothing useful on how to fix it.

I've checked my quota in google api console just to make sure is not that I hit the limit or anything but that is not it.

EDIT: 
Also, this is not only for my development website. It is happening in all websites that I access running the google map api v3.

Any light shed on this would be most helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps - Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type image/png](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500381/goolge-maps-resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-imag)

Comment: Ah Yes, it is a dupliccate just by couple of hours difference. Anyways, the answer seems to be the version of the api used. Instead of `v3.exp` use: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.16"></script>`